# How to get two msg from different Handlers together?

Tags: android

Here are two Handler:

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
      case MESSAGE_A:
        break;
    }
  }
}

Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
      case MESSAGE_ONE:
        doSomethingOne();
        break;
      case MESSAGE_TWO:
        doSomethingTwo();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I can guarantee that `MESSAGE_A` and `MESSAGE_ONE`(or `MESSAGE_TWO`) will be sent in pairs, but don't know which one is the first. Now I want call `doSomethingOne()` only if handle `MESSAGE_A` and `MESSAGE_ONE`, call `doSomethingTwo()` only if handle `MESSAGE_A` and `MESSAGE_TWO`.

For example, I receive `MESSAGE_ONE`, now I need to wait for `MESSAGE_A`, then call doSomethingOne().

Similarly, I receive `MESSAGE_A`, now I need to wait for `MESSAGE_TWO`(or `MESSAGE_ONE`), then call doSomethingTwo()(or `doSomethingOne`).

What should I do?

Comment: what is your output now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the MESSAGE_A, MESSAGE_ONE, and MESSAGE_TWO are **DIFFERENT**.
2. write a method outside your handler classes, e.g. handleMessageTogether(message m)
3. in the method handleMessage() of your handler class, call the handleMessageTogether() method instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. For example, MESSAGE_ONE is sent, then MESSAGE_A, how does your solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `handler2` from `handler1` (when case message A). For example instead of sending messages `messageone` and `messagetwo`, you can do that with boolean, then when `messageA` is finished, call `handler2` and see which `boolean` is true.

Comment: `MESSAGE_A` and `MESSAGE_ONE`(or `MESSAGE_TWO`) appear in uncertain order, I don't think your solution can resolve my problem. See my examples above.